# Debug problem occurs sometimes in Silverlight when in Chrome

Tags: debugging, silverlight-4.0, stack-overflow

I am using a dedicated test SL web application that hosts SL object I am debugging.
I am debugging using basic F5 and use browser Google Chrome. Sometimes a bug happens, how I reproduce it.

I was running build->debug like 100 times already, but then I made a mistake that caused StackOverflowException and happened in main page constructor and afterwards when I rebuild and hit F5 it says no symbols have been loaded. Note that NOTHING has changed , I use the same 2 buttons combinations rebuild solution-> start debugging.

In order for debug to continue to attach I need to close XAML main page , open it again (in visual stuido) and hit rebuild ->f5 again, afterwards it works fine. (found this solution after SOME time)

I am not sure whats bugged but it appears to be a bug somewhere in SL to me.
Question is - whats going on maybe someone can explain.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior using a different browser?

Comment: i will try to test , but im 99% sure it will be the same. I cant see how new chrome instances would remember that there was a stackoverflow thrown before in VS. but who knows..

Comment: unfortunately I cannot reproduce it for now. But bug with Silverlight debugging occures to me too often to be my fault. Theres something bugged and or at least something is not configured correctly because debugger behaviour can be described as "strange" for minimum sometimes. I really cannot predict whether current rebuild->Start debugging WILL load symbols for breakpoints to work or WILL NOT..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually error was super simple, I wasn't understanding how "exactly" xap works, it was a little more magical to me than it is. I just needed to rebuild & clear cache in browser ( chrome in this case) to attach successfully. For some reason I thought that local version doesn't require clear cache call.

Actually chrome is pretty bad to debug silverlight so I recommend IE for this sole purpose, sometimes debugger simply fails to attach to chrome, in that case you usually need to do this by attach to process - choose chrome with silverlight name there.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like Chrome's isolation mode for plug-ins. Generally speaking it's best to manually attach to the Chrome process that is running Silverlight (which isn't always one VS attaches to when pressing F5).